# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasFocus' of undefined

Tags: ckeditor

just downloaded and loaded ckeditor (downloaded thru build editor) to my app the editor is loading but ca t do anything

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasFocus' of undefined line 636 of ckeditor.js

i simply load it like this

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="analyseEditor" data-id="${analyse.id}" style="margin-top: 60px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 id="form-title"><i class="fa fa fa-question"></i>Editeur de questions</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="analyseEditorBody">
        <form>
             <textarea name="editor" id="editor">
                test
             </textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

then call

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
```

...

an idear ?

thanks